# how to create a function in python which makes it possible to return frequencies to zeros

Tags: python

how to create a function in python which makes it possible to return frequencies to zeros and it is done manually from a device called the zvh8 through buttons which does this and my objective is to return this task under form of a code in python to make this task automatic . i try to make it in a list but dosen't work in the device it works in the console and i try to make it worked on the device .this is the code that i tryed :

```
m1=instr.query(" CALC:MARK1:Y?")
m2=instr.query(" CALC:MARK2:Y?")
m3=instr.query(" CALC:MARK3:Y?")
m4=instr.query(" CALC:MARK4:Y?")
m5=instr.query(" CALC:MARK5:Y?")
m6=instr.query(" CALC:MARK6:Y?")

A=[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6]

def ZEROING(A):
    
    
    if all(A)==0:
        
        pass
    else:
        
        for i in range(len(A)):
            
           A[i]=0
    return A


A
```

Comment: Are you asking why nothing happens if you don't call the function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.